# nginx settings location mis-downloading

Tags: wordpress, nginx, phpmyadmin, php

I'm setting up nginx with php5-fpm on Ubuntu 12.04LTS for wordpress and phpMyAdmin.

My phpMyAdmin locates in`/var/www/phpMyAdmin`, wordpress in `/home/user/workspace/wordpress`, MySQL at `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`

I want to map `/` to wordpress, `/phpmyadmin` to phpMyAdmin, so how can I achieve this??

Wordpress seemed OK, but when accessing `/phpmyadmin`, the browser "downloads" the request as files...??

This is my current nginx.conf:

```
server {
    listen 8000;
    root /home/user/workspace/wordpress;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;\

    location ~* /phpmyadmin { #TODO: shall here be a  tailing slash??
        #TODO: root or alias???
    }

    location ~ \..*/.*\.php$ {
        return 403;
    }
    location / {
        #TODO: show the following line be un-commented??
        #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
        # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
        # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;#TODO: could this being removed??
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    #FIXME: and how to block all access to /home/user/workspace/wordpress/server.d/*
    #This doesn't work??
    location /sever\.d {
        autoindex on;
        deny all;
    }
```

And, what permission should I set for both the directory `wordpress/` and `phpMyAdmin/` if all the servers are running as `www-data:www-data`??
Currently I set them as `755 user:www-data`, is that correct??

I haven't set up server under linux yet, I was using those servers under WinXP, so I'm trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in you between location add this

```
location /phpmyadmin {
           root /usr/share/;
           index index.php index.html index.htm;
           location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
                   try_files $uri =404;
                   root /usr/share/;
                   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                   fastcgi_index index.php;
                   fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                   include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
           }
           location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
                   root /usr/share/;
           }
    }
    location /phpMyAdmin {
           rewrite ^/* /phpmyadmin last;
    }
```

anywhere between   
also
your missing a server name. type in a server_name example.com;

Comment: so I must setup another cgi handler for phpmyadmin??